# Use text features as a multilabel problem

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-processing, quanteda

Introducing as data structure the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested.","Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.","Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries."), label1 = c(1,1,1), label2 = c(0,1,0), label3 = c(1,0,0))
```

Columns with names label1, label2 and label3 are some kind of categories and 1 means the text from column text belongs to this category.

Using text features from text features in combination with the label columns how it could be possible to introduce a new dataframe which contains the text column and use a multilable algorithm to categorize the new data into the label columns?

Example new data frame testing set:

```
dfnew <- data.frame(text = c("Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.","There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable."))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "use a multilable algorithm to categorize the new data into the label columns"? Do you mean training and predicting the label for each text separately, using each label1 label2 label3 as training data? If so you will have a problem in this example with a lack of variation in label1.

Comment: @KenBenoit thank you. Yes this is what I mean. In the real dataset I have different structure but I tried a small example just to receive some help on how to start the process. It is possible one text categorized into 1 or more labels

Comment: @KenBenoit do you think it could be possible an example with the work flow?

Comment: Yes, then you should try a multi-class classifier such as Naive Bayes, using each label category as a training label. See `quanteda.textmodels::textmodel_nb()`. This will be a separate fitting and prediction for each label.